# Subscribing to ALL ActorEvents

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In my WebApi I want to subscribe to the ActorEvents for **all** of my ActorIds.  [Subscribing to a single ActorId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-events) is easy, and works.  However, I'm wondering if there is a way to subscribe everything all and future ones at once, that I might've missed in the documentation.

Currently, I'm iterating through all my ActorIds on WebApi startup and subscribing.  I then subscribe to new Ids, and unsubscribe from deleted ones.  However, this is somewhat cumbersome, and since it is during startup, will throw errors and stop the api process if any of the actors aren't up and running (happens on deployment).

Also for consideration, is that the same ActorId may be used in multiple IActors.  For example UserActor(Bob), Wishlist(Bob), etc.

Any suggestions on how best to subscribe to anything?

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't subscribe to future Actor events, because they don't exist yet. As a workaround, you can make the Actors register themselves to a central hub, as they are created. And use that instead of `ActorEvents`. One way to do this is by using something like [pub/sub](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.pubsubactors).
2. An `ActorId` simply identifies an Actor and it is used to determine the `ActorService` partition it is stored on. It does not hold Actor type info, sou it's safe to re-use it across different Actor types.