# Service Fabric increasing thread count

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We've noticed that the thread count of our Actors and WebApi increases over time, even when idle, in service fabric.

Details:

- On-premise cluster using the 5.7.198.9494 version.
- Development cluster (e.g all node types on 1 box, not multi-machine)
- ~100 unique actor ids; each with ~15 actor services (e.g UserActor, WishlistActor, etc)
- Each of the actors services emits ActorEvents.  These are subscribed to by the WebApi, which uses SignalR v2 to send the event data to UI clients.

My gut feeling is that I'm subscribing to ActorEvents incorrectly ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953525/subscribing-to-all-actorevents) about subscribing to ActorEvents).  Since it's difficult to know whether I've subscribed to the actor before, I might subscribe multiple times.  However, I'm not seeing an increase in thread count when I do this, at least not immediately.

Looking at procexp the threads taking up CPU utilization are clr.dll!InstallCustomModule+0x1c00.  There are also **tons** of ntdll.dll!RtReleaseSRWLockExclusive+0x1370 that take up very little cpu utilization as a single unit, but it adds up over a whole.  They don't seem to be release.

Any ideas how to prevent this decay in usability?

*Edit*: Fixed procexp's name